# Same input file twice, error in table of contents

Tags: input, table-of-contents

I'm having some difficulties with my table of contents. I want my conclusion to be in the start of the document and in the end. To do this I've included the same input file twice as you can see here in my main documents

```
\include{Preamble}
\begin{document}
\include{Sektioner/Forside}
\mbox{  }
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{0}
\include{Sektioner/Resume}
\include{Sektioner/Konklusion}
\include{Sektioner/Indledning}
\include{Sektioner/Teori}
\include{Sektioner/Forsoegsbeskrivelse}
\include{Sektioner/Forsoegsresultater}
\include{Sektioner/Databehandling}
\include{Sektioner/SHIPFLOW}
\include{Sektioner/Fuldskala}
\include{Sektioner/Propel}
\include{Sektioner/Engines}
\include{Sektioner/Resultater}
\include{Sektioner/Konklusion}
\include{Appendiks/Appendiks}
\end{document}
```

But it's showing up wrong. The first conclusion in the beginning of the documents links to the second conclusion (which are both the same). Here's a picture to show

[image]

It's showing up right when going through the documents as you can see

[image]

I hope you can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Use `\input{Preamble}` and not `\include`, which is for text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are `\include`ing exactly the same file, `Sektioner/Konklusion`, twice,
probably with `\chapter` at the top.  this will get two entries in `.aux` files,
with two different values for the chapter and page numbers,
but the last one read in is what will be used in the table of contents -- twice.

you need to have two different `\chapter` lines to get two different toc lines.

i suggest breaking the "Konklusion" file into three parts:

- a file `Sektioner/Konklusion-text.tex` containing everything except the initial `\chapter` line;
- a file `Sektioner/Konklusion1.tex` containing two lines:

  ```
  \chapter{Konklusion}
  \input{Konklusion-text}
  ```
- a file `Sektioner/Konklusion2.tex` with contents exactly the same as "Konklusion1`.

then you can

```
\include{Sektioner/Konklusion1}
...
\include{Sektioner/Konklusion2}
```

and the resulting contents list will have the correct chapter and page numbers.

Comment: Arh, of course. Thanks a lot, that helped wonders.